# How to create and load new wallet using multi-wallet feature (bitcoin-core v0.15.0)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I want to use bitcoin-core for many users and with the new version it became possible. I have no idea how to use this new feature. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Multiwallet are currently only available through the RPC interface for programmers and command-line users.[ref](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2017/09/01/release-0.15.0/#multiwallet)

Multi-wallet is enabled by using more than one `-wallet` argument when starting Bitcoin, either on the command line or in the Bitcoin config file.

<sub>[Multi-wallet support](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.15.0#multi-wallet-support)</sub>

Comment: Yep, I read it in docs. So it means for adding new wallet I should restart daemon?

Comment: You can use it only by RPC calls or with cli, which means in runtime.

Comment: I know it. But for adding new wallet I should start daemon with wallets which I want to use. My question meant is it possible to do this without restarting?

Comment: Yes, to add new wallet you must restart the daemon.

Comment: Have recent versions made any changes to how users can access multiple wallets?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick you can check the changelogs for last version here https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.20.0